# How to improve the performance of a 10 min running query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which is taking approximately 10 mins to execute and produce the results. When I try to break it into parts and run it, it seems to run fine, within seconds.

I tried to modify the subselect of the top and the bottom portions of the query and determine if that was causing the issue, but it was not. It gave out some results within 3 seconds.

I am trying to learn to read the Estimated Execution plan, but it is becoming more confusing and hard for me to trace to the issue.

Can anyone please point out some mistakes which I made that is making the query for long?

```
Select Distinct
       PostExtended.BatchNum,
       post.ControlNumStatus,
       post.AccountSeg,
       Post.PostDat
From
       Post 
       Post Records 
    join (Select Post, MAX(Dist) as Dist, COUNT(fkglDist) as RecordCount From PostExtend WITH (NOLOCK) Group By flPost) as PostExtender on Post.PK = PostExtender.flPost
    join glPostExtended WITH (NOLOCK) on glPostExtendedLimiter.Post = glPostExtended.Post and (PostExtendedLimiter.fkglDist = PostExtend.Dist or PostExtend.Dist is null)
       join (select lP.fkosControlNumberStatus, lP.SourceJENumber, AccountSegment,
                 sum(case
                    ............
                from Post WITH (NOLOCK)
                  join AccountingPeriod WITH (NOLOCK) on AccountingPeriod.pk = lP.fkglAccountingPeriod
                  join FiscalYear WITH (NOLOCK) on FiscalYear.pk = AccountingPeriod.FiscalYear
                  join Account WITH (NOLOCK) on Account.pk = FiscalYear.Account
                where FiscalYear.Period = @Date
                and glP.fkMLSosCodeEntryType = 2202
                group by glP.fkosControlNumberStatus, glP.SourceNumber, AccountSeg) post on post.ControlNumStatus = Post.fkControlNumberStatus and postdata.SourceJENumber = glPost.SourceJENumber
                where post.AmountT <> 0)......
                Group by
```

Comment: `Can anyone please assist me in improving the performance of this query?` <= No but you can. Get the complete actual execution plan and analyze that. It should tell you which operations are the most expensive relative to the query as a whole. Then you can focus on those parts and re-execute until the performance becomes acceptable.

Comment: Looking at it, it would need a lot of work to improve. Unsure why you are using with(nolock), as well as joining onto such large sub queries.  You would also need to provide details on the indexes on all joining tables along with the execution plan before anyone can offer any advice.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: As this is clearly an accounting system you need to take out those nolock hints and then forget that hint even exists. You can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows as well a whole list of other nasty things with that hint. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ It is NOT a magic go faster button, it carries some serious baggage.

Comment: And to add to this - "distinct" is often a cover-up of a logically-incorrect query.

Comment: @Igor The way I had phrased the "assist me" part might have sounded like "Fix it for me". But I definitely want to learn how to approach a complex query like this to improve its performance.

Comment: @StraightUp - my point was that no one can fix it for you mostly because you never included an execution plan. You need to use the execution plan to figure out what part(s) are slow and address those one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subqueries are very often the point of problems.

I would try to:

- separate the **postdata** subquery from the main query,
- save the result in a temporary table or even in a table variable,
- put clustered index on **fkosControlNumberStatus** and **SourceJENumber** fields,
- join this temporary table back to the main query.

Sometimes the result of these simple actions pleasantly surprises.

Comment: Temp table is exactly what I had to use and it improved the performance like into 1 second. I am very new to SQL and optimization, it took me a long time to search and find out about temp tables, using `INTO`...and it was crazy how it made a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex query.  You are joining on Aggregate Queries (with GROUP BY).

The first thing I would do is see how long it takes to run each of the join queries.  One of these may run very fast, while another may run very long.  So, you may not really need to optimize the entire query--just one of the joined queries.

Another way to do it is just start eliminating joins one by one, then run the entire query and see how fast it goes.  When you have a really significant decrease in time, you've found the error.

Typically, one thing that can add a lot of CPU is comparisons.  The sums with case statements might be the biggest suspect.

Have you used the Database Engine Tuning Adviser?  If all else fails, go with that and see what it tells you.

So, maybe try this approach:

1. Take away the CASE Statements inside the SUM expressions on that last join.
2. Remove the last JOIN with all the sums.
3. Remove the first join with that GROUP BY and the MAX expression

That would be my strategy.

Comment: The user wants magic and you suggested the only real way to determine what is going on. I would add breaking down the query into multiple one step queries by storing results into temp tables which are then used by the next query. It will quickly become obvious which step is running very slowly.